# Use an alternate dependency list for Node.JS + NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, npm

Is it possible to have two `package.json` files for a single NodeJS project?

In a project I'm working on, there is an optional and experimental feature which requires some node packages of its own. For every day development, I do not want to force all developers to install those packages.

What I'd like, essentially, is a file which just lists npm dependencies in the a similar format as `package.json`, and then use `npm install` to install all of them.

eg:

```
// package.json:
{
    "dependencies": {
        "underscore": "1.1.7",
        "connect": "1.7.0"
    }
}

// alt.json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "experimental_package": "0.0.1",
        "and_another_one": "1.33.7"
    }
}
```

And then, something like:

```
$ npm install
// install the regular package.json stuff
$ npm install alt.json
// install the other ones
```

Please note that this is *not* the same as `devDependencies`

Comment: That seems like an ideal situation for using a branch in your source control repository.

Comment: the "experimental feature" exists alongside the regular application. It's just that I don't want to force other developers into installing extra dependencies and adding barriers to getting started just for this.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a small script (even in Node.js) so that it executes 'npm install .' twice: one for the original package.json and then for alt.json (package.json gets renamed to _package.json and alt.json gets renamed to package.json; after that's finished rename the files as they were).

I'm not sure about this I've never tried, but I think it could work.